# SQL query builder WPF

Tags: c#, .net, sql, wpf, components

I need to give my customers an ability to select virtually any data from the database. They are regular users, don't know SQL, know nothing about tables, relations etc.

Is there some component/tool with simple GUI that I can customize for my database structure?

Right now I need it for WPF project, but I'm also interested in ASP.NET tool for future.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “virtually any data”?

Answer (score 1):

You could provide your users with a flattened view of the data that denormalizes across relationships (since regular users don't 'get' relationships) and provide them with the ability to choose which columns the want to see and which values they want to filter on

Answer (score 0):

Try [EasyQuery.NET](http://devtools.korzh.com/eq/dotnet/). 
It seems they have released WPF version recently (I'm subscribed to their newsletter).